# Why does repeated memory allocation in windows slow down?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to understand why the following code behaves differently on my linux and windows 7 machines:
On linux it takes ~120ms per iteration.
On windows 7 already the first iteration takes 0.4 seconds and subsequent iterations take much longer. Iteration 8 already takes about 11 seconds, iteration 22 takes roughly 1 minute.

I observed this behaviour on different hardware. It seems to be related to windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>

void iteration() {
  int n = 25000;
  // Allocate memory
  long** blocks = new long*[n];
  for( int i = 0; i<n; ++i )
  {
    blocks[i] = new long[100008];
  }
  // Free all allocated memory
  for( int i = 0; i<n; ++i )
  {
    delete[] blocks[i];
  }
  delete[] blocks;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int nbIter = 30;
  for( int i = 0; i < nbIter; ++i )
  {
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    iteration();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "Iteration #" << i << ": time=" << elapsed.count() << "ms" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what happens here, and how to get the code to run stable on windows?

edit: I did a release build in VS2013 on windows, I executed the program from outside VS.
here are some more exact running times (in seconds):

```
Iteration #0: time=0.381000
Iteration #1: time=0.391000
Iteration #2: time=0.451000
Iteration #3: time=1.507000
Iteration #4: time=1.711000
Iteration #5: time=2.938000
Iteration #6: time=4.770000
Iteration #7: time=7.840000
Iteration #8: time=10.563000
Iteration #9: time=14.606000
Iteration #10: time=20.732000
Iteration #11: time=24.948000
Iteration #12: time=30.255000
Iteration #13: time=34.608000
Iteration #14: time=38.114000
Iteration #15: time=43.217000
Iteration #16: time=39.926000
Iteration #17: time=43.506000
Iteration #18: time=43.660000
Iteration #19: time=45.291000
Iteration #20: time=50.003000
```

Comment: Are you running in a debugger?

Comment: The heap implementation is going to be compiler, rather than platform, specific. A different toolchain on windows would likely have a different result. There are in fact a number of projects that promise to improve the perfomance of apps that are heap-bound by providing custom operator new and operator delete implementations.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain `iteration` isn't being compiled out? It doesn't do anything or produce any side effects, so the compiler should be free to junk the whole thing.

Comment: Are you comparing release builds? Is the very specific number `100008` significant?

Comment: If you're using VS / msbuild, are you building in "release" mode?  "Debug" modes may provide extra instrumentation of dynamic memory usage and/or array indexing, which could compromise performance....

Comment: If you are running it from inside the debugger (even if it is a release build) the memory allocation and freeing is extremely slow. You must perform the measurment from commandline to get realistic results.

Comment: If you want stable performance, why not try a different compiler on windows?

Comment: I checked both release and debug builds. On Linux the difference was almost non-existant, which might be a hint that it is compiled out. However if everything is compiled out, 120 ms seems to be awfully long for doing nothing.

I reported the running time of the release build on windows, when the application is started manually, not from VS.

Comment: This could possibly be caused by Linux not committing a memory allocation until that memory is being used. If you're building with VS on Windows, it could be caused by different strategies for when to release memory back to the operating system. (I would suspect that you're running out of physical RAM on Windows.)

Comment: @molbdnilo no, 100008 is not significant, however the strange running time shows only if enough memory is allocated. For much smaller numbers (maybe depending on the machine) I get consistent running time.

I also dont think that I run out of physical RAM. I have 16GB on windows (compared to 4GB on linux) and the taskmanager claims to have over 1GB free memory duing execution.

Comment: And there is no way that `iteration` takes 120 ms if it has been optimised out.

Comment: Agreed. Have to throw myself on my sword over that suggestion.

Comment: Confirmed on Windows 10, VS2015, x64 (in debug, release, inside and outside IDE). Really odd. It probably has something to do with the allocation logic for the C++ std library that VS uses.

Comment: What CRT are you linking against? The one that ships with VS 2013, or the Universal CRT that ships with Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Digging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810603.aspx) [around](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/06/26/what-a-heap-of-part-one/) in the [references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx) about the [heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810603.aspx) on Windows (as well as [some](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1081496) [infosec](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/heap-overflow-vulnerability-and-heap-internals-explained/) [articles](http://www.leviathansecurity.com/blog/understanding-the-windows-allocator-a-redux) on it), there are some tidbits about [common heap slow downs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx#heap3_commonproblems) which states that a few are

- Slowdown as a result of allocation operations.
- Slowdown as a result of free operations.
- Slowdown as a result of frequent allocs and reallocs.

Which does help to explain why there is a slow down (i.e. frequent allocs and reallocs), but it doesn't really explain *why* there is a slow down.

The first thing that should be noted is that `sizeof(long) != sizeof(long)`, that is, in the tests I did with 64-bit builds using `g++` and Visual Studio 12, `sizeof(long)` on Windows was *4* and on Linux it was *8*. This is an important note when allocating/deallocating memory. If you change your code from the `long` type to a type where `sizeof(T) == 8` (like `long long`) then the issue goes away and the times are consistent across iterations. Example:

```
void iteration() {
    int n = 25000;
    // Allocate memory
    long long** blocks = new long long*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        blocks[i] = new long long[100008];
    }
    // Free all allocated memory
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        delete[] blocks[i];
    }
    delete[] blocks;
}
// sizeof(long long) == 8 on my Linux/Unix and Windows 64-bit machines
```

It should also be noted that the timing issue goes away only for *exactly* **this** code.

If you keep the type of `long long` but adjusted `100008` to say `16666`, the issue comes up again; further, if you changed it to `16668` and ran the `long long` iteration immediately followed by the `long` version, the timing would go *up* for the `long long` function, then *down* for the `long`, example:

```
template < typename T >
void iteration() {
    int n = 25000;
    // Allocate memory
    T** blocks = new T*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        blocks[i] = new T[16668];
    }
    // Free all allocated memory
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        delete[] blocks[i];
    }
    delete[] blocks;
}

for (int i = 0; i < nbItrs; ++i) {
    iteration<long long>(); // time goes UP
}
for (int i = 0; i < nbItrs; ++i) {
    iteration<long>(); // time goes DOWN
}
```

Additionally the posted code produces similar results using `malloc`/`free`, `LocalAlloc`/`LocalFree` and/or `HeapAlloc`/`HeapFree` since `new`/`malloc` (on Windows) calls `HeapAlloc`. The reason has to do with how Windows manages it's heap memory and the locations of the freed memory. When pages have to be deleted, clean up on the free block list needs to be done and the list might need to be adjusted accordingly.

It's this adjustment that can take time, during the search and replace or removal of the old blocks of memory from the list. If the blocks don't fall on clean boundaries, additional adjustments might need to be done to the list of free heap blocks.

Going deeper into the how and why of Windows heap management would involve explaining the design of the Windows kernel and it's memory management. Getting into that would go beyond the scope of this question/answer but, [some](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1081496) of the [articles](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/heap-overflow-vulnerability-and-heap-internals-explained/) I linked to [above](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx) have great overviews and explain quite well that how and why.

However, you did ask

> how to get the code to run stable on windows?

As stated above, changing the type would allow more consistent timing, additionally, as stated in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36767883/1152524), deleting the list in reverse order will also achieve more consistent timings;

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; --i )
{
    delete[] blocks[i-1];
}
```

This is due to the fact that the Windows memory manger uses a singly linked list to maintain the heap locations, hence why the times can go up when `delete`ing since the list is being traversed and why the times can be slower on Windows compared to Linux (though my tests actually produced similar times in both doing these changes).

I hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough reseach. I will wait a couple more days to see if other answers come up, otherwise I will accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.  I was able to reproduce.

I get consistent - albeit still somewhat sluggish - performance by `delete[]`-ing the blocks in reverse order of their allocation:

```
for( int i = 0; i<n; ++i )
    delete[] blocks[n - 1 - i];
```

I suspect it may all relate to coalescing overheads - from [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx):

> Slowdown as a result of free operations. Free operations consume more cycles, mainly if coalescing is enabled. During coalescing, each free operation should "find" its neighbors, pull them out to construct a larger block, and reinsert the larger block into the free list. During that find, memory may be touched in a random order, causing cache misses and performance slowdown.

There are few weird things about it though:

- my measurements showed that while `delete[]` took ~80% of the time on the first iteration or three, after half a dozen more `new[]` was taking almost as long.
- the problem kicked in very suddenly as I went from `new long[91134]` to ...`91135`: that's very nearly 356kb, but I didn't manage to google anything related.

Comment: I can confirm that freeing in reverse order improves the running time: one iteration now takes roughly 1.3 seconds, no siginificant slow down over multiple iterations but still way slower than on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting problem. I cannot reproduce it on Windows 10 with MS Visual Studio Community 2013, however if you are allocating / deallocating lots of memory blocks with fixed size, you could try to replace new/delete with fixed-size memory block allocation algorithm, also known as memory pool. It works much faster and with constant speed. Here you can find an example based on BSD license: https://github.com/moya-lang/Allocator. Maybe that could help.